# Create Public Selector that can be accessed from anywhere

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-optimization

My project has a function that is being used from 3000+ places. How to make the SEL public and access it!

```
struct MyClass {
 func method(arg1: String, arg2: Int) {


 }
}
```

I want something like:

```
var publicSelector: Selector = MyClass.method(_:)
```

That can be used as a public function. Without changing the declaration place.

Comment: Why do you need a selector for that, why don't you declare your method as `static`, and simply call `MyClass.method`?

Comment: MyClass.method use will increase the run time as it uses method lookup and call stack push and pop every time :)

Comment: Swift uses static dispatch, I don't think the overhead (if it exists) will be more with the use of `MyClass.method` compared to calling/ performing the selector. It probably make sense if you are using `@objc` annotation to run it in Objective-C runtime or calling an Objective-C method (dynamic dispatch) otherwise I think you are overcomplicating the issue at hand